# How to deal with "Your Apple ID currently has two-step verification turned on, but two-factor authentication is required." on developer.apple.com?

Tags: apple-id, developer-program, two-factor-authentication

[image: Apple Developer page]

https://developer.apple.com/apple-id/

> Your Apple ID currently has two-step verification turned on, *but
>   two-factor authentication is required.* After you turn on two-factor
>   authentication, signing in to your developer account will require both
>   your password and access to your trusted devices or trusted phone
>   number.

How to make this 2-step auth?..
I was trying to login, and it didn't ask me to put SMS code or something else.

It means, *"signing in to your developer account will require both
your password and access to your trusted devices or trusted phone
 number"* never happened.

In the same time it does ask 2-step auth on https://appleid.apple.com/.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two-step authentication is an older method of authentication for your Apple-ID. This is no longer "good enough" to be used with developer accounts.

You MUST upgrade to two-factor authentication as a developer. There's no way to login as a develop with two-step authentication anymore.

Apple has a detailed guide on enabling two-factor authentication here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

Basically you take your iOS device, open Settings and click your name at the top. Choose "Password & Security" and then tap "Turn On Two-Factor Authentication". You'll then be guided through how to verify your phone number.

If you want to do the same from a Mac, you have to open System Preferences and click "Apple ID". Choose "Password & Security" from the menu on the left and then click the "Turn On..." button alongside "Two-Factor Authentication".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to make it w/o an Apple device?

Comment: Yes, you can use a Windows PC with iCloud for Windows installed.